# register on github something went wrong

Tags: github, registration

I have problems with a cordova plugin, so I wanted to report an issue in github. But when I try to register, my browser says "something went wrong" when I type in something - in every textfield! 
I tried with Edge, Google Chrome, Opera and Firefox. 
How to fix this problem? Or is it not possible for everybody at the moment?

Comment: This seems like a question for Github, not StackOverflow. Why not try contacting their help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use directly "sign up" and not after clicking "new issue" and then sign up